Broken pipe error while ajax request is being sent to django
I'm creating a speedcube timer with django, basically it shows a way to scramble my cube and I can time how long it takes me to solve it. At the moment I've just implemented the timer function with js. After I stop the timer, it sends me the time through an ajax request to a view that creates a solve object which has time as one of its attributes.
The problem is that I get a broken pipe error in the console in the place of the post request even though the function is called and the object is created, also when in the developer tools the fetch request appears as cancelled.
This is my first solo project, I'm not following any tutorial, and I don't know js so please if you have any advice to optimize anything i'd appreciate it.
HTML:
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
    <title>TimerJS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="clock">
            <input class="number" type="text" maxlength="2" value="00" readonly><span>:</span><input class="number" type="text" maxlength="2" value="00" readonly><span>:</span><input class="number" type="text" maxlength="2" value="00" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button id="play" onclick="startTimer()"></button>
            <button id="stop" onclick="stopTimer()"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'js/timer.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>

JS:
let inputs, clock, alarm, minutes = 0, seconds = 0, decseconds = 0,repeater; /* Declaro todas las variables que necesito */

window.addEventListener('load', () => { /* Espero a que cargue el documento */
    clock = document.querySelector('.clock'); /* Busco el reloj */
});

/* Funcion principal */
function startTimer() { 

    setTimer();  /* Seteo el timer visualmente */
    countdown()  /* Arranco el contador */

}

/* Funcion para cambiar el timer en la pantalla y en la pestaña */
function setTimer() {
    /* Cambio la hora en pantalla */
    clock.innerHTML = `<p class="number">${minutes > 9 ? minutes : ('0' + minutes)}</p><span>:</span><p class="number">${seconds > 9 ? seconds : ('0' + seconds)}</p><span>:</span><p class="number">${decseconds > 9 ? decseconds : ('0' + decseconds)}`;
}

/* Funcion que arranca el contador */
function countdown() {
    repeater = setInterval(runner,10);
}

/* Funcion que cuenta */
function runner() {
    /* Si tengo más de 0 segundos, restá segundos */
    /* Si tengo 0 segundos pero tengo más de 0 minutos, poné segundos en 59 y restale 1 a minutos */
    /* Si tengo 0 segundos, 0 minutos pero tengo más de 0 horas, poné segundos en 59, minutos en 59 y restale 1 a horas */
    /* Sino arranca la alarma */
    decseconds++
    if (decseconds%100 == 0) {
        seconds++;
        decseconds = 0
    } else {
        if (seconds == 60) {
            seconds = 0
            minutes++;
        }
    }
    
    setTimer();
}

/* Funcion para detener el timer */
function stopTimer(){
    clearInterval(repeater);
    location.reload();
    sentTime();
}

function sentTime(){

    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    const url = "save_solve/";
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')},
        // mode: 'same-origin'
    }

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('minutes', minutes);
    formData.append('seconds', seconds);
    formData.append('decseconds', decseconds);
    options['body'] = formData;

    fetch(url, options)
};

view from Python:
def save_time(request):
    ms = int(request.POST.get('decseconds'))*10
    s = int(request.POST.get('seconds'))
    m = int(request.POST.get('minutes'))
    print(f'{m}:{s}:{ms}')
    solve = Solve()
    solve.solve_time = datetime.timedelta(minutes=m, seconds=s, milliseconds=ms)
    solve.save()
    return HttpResponse('Sí se ejecutó la petición')

I tried to remove some code, because I think something is taking too long, but it didn't work. I'm considering taking the part that creates the object and put it in a asynchronous task, perhaps with celery.
